# Stabilizer of $1$ on $S_6$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, galois-theory

$S_6$ acts on the set $\{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6\}$ by permutation. Explicitly describe $(S_6)1$ the stabilizer of $1$ in $S_6$.

I understand that I want to list all the elements that fix $1$ in the permutation, such as $(2\ 3)$ or $(2\ 3\ 4)$, but does this mean I need to list every permutation that would occur and test them?  Wouldn't that amount to $720$ different permutations that would need to be tested?  I feel like I'm going about this the wrong way.

Comment: You can be explicit without tediously listing each and every permutation in (S6)1. Instead, you can give an explicit *mathematical* description of the permutations in (S6)1, as is done for example in the answer of @Akababa.

Comment: Wouldn't the Stabilizer of 1 of S6 be any permutation in S6 that does not include 1?

Comment: Permutations do not "include" elements of the set $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, although they may "stabilize" elements of that set.

Comment: I see in @Akababa's answer, he is stated (1)a for all a that exists in S5... is this just the identity permuting with S5?

Answer (score 2):

$S_5$ acts on $\{2,3,4,5,6\}$ by permutation, so your answer is $\{(1)a:a\in S_5\}$

Comment: I'm still a bit lost.  Could you explain this further ? I think I am misunderstanding what a stabilizer is then.

Comment: If you fix 1, you essentially get a permutation on the remaining 5 elements.

Comment: {(1)a:a∈S5}... but wouldn't that then not fix 1 that exists in S5?  Sorry, I'm really confused.

Comment: You would just consider $S_5$ "shifted" to act on 2,3,4,5,6 instead of 1,2,3,4,5. Remember that the actual value of the elements isn't important, you can permute {alice, apple, cat, pepsi, stackexchange} just like {1,2,3,4,5} or {2,3,4,5,6}

Comment: Ok, so because we are asking for the stabilizer of 1, we are keeping 1 fixed.  This means, the other 5 elements are permuting on themselves. So, when you wrote the answer is (1)a for all a in S5, what does the (1)a mean, just the identity 1 * a?  or the element 1 in operation with any element in S5?

Comment: It's a little abuse of notation, as you would normally write a permutation as (1)(23456), I'm writing it as (1)a instead. Try thinking of the problem when you fix 6 instead, then it's just a permutation on 12345.

Comment: Would it be correct to also write it as 1*a for any a that exists in S5 (as this describes (1)(23456) or (1)(12345) as you stated?

Comment: I'm not sure, but there's nothing wrong with using words if there's no notation that expresses your intentions exactly

Answer (score 0):

The group of permutation that fixes one element you can think it as a group $G\subset S_6$ such that is $G\cong S_5$.